# Issue in finding Tracking Id for Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have to integrate Google Analytics in my Android app.

Completed all the code for it But, Having one issue.

**The Issue is** taking **Tracking ID** from my google analytics account.

According to the Document :

==> To find the Google Analytics ID (Tracking Id):

1. Sign in to your Analytics account.
2. Click Admin.
3. Select an account from the menu in the ACCOUNT column.
4. Select a property from the menu in the PROPERTY column.
5. Under PROPERTY, click Tracking Info > Tracking Code. Your Google Analytics ID is displayed at the top of the page.

But, I can't find **Tracking Info** Option or any **Tracking Code** there according to the step number : 5.

From where can I get Tracking Id which look like this one : `(UA-41888835-6)` ?

NOTE : I can find Property Id there.

Comment: For the Solution, I have integrated Firebase from my Android Studio and then you can integrate your firebase project in Google Analytics. So the solution is implementing Google Analytics with Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Solution,

I have integrated Firebase from my Android Studio and then you can integrate your firebase project in Google Analytics. So the solution is **implementing Google Analytics with Firebase.**

Answer (score 5):

While creating property click on advanced option and enable "Create a Universal Analytics property". This will [image: select show advanced option]

Then enable "Create a Universal Analytics property"

[image: select - "Create both a Google Analytics 4 and a Universal Analytics property"]

then lick next and complete the property creation, now you will have two different properties created. Now choose the universal property where you will find the tracking info. GA4 will not have tracking info.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to get the Tracking ID in Google Analytics:

1. If you are using **web properties**, then Tracking ID is in **Admin / Property / Tracking Info / Tracking Code**, just as you noted in your question.
2. If you are using **App + Web properties**, things get a little bit more complicated. **For Android and iOS apps Data Streams, there is no tracking ID** as to have GA tracking, you need to add Firebase in your app and link your GA account with Firebase.

However if you are using a **web Data Stream**, you can get the Tracking ID (although it is called **Measurement ID**) from **Admin / Property / Data Stream / Web**.

You may read more details on this article https://analyticshelp.io/blog/google-analytics-property-tracking-id/

Comment: Why on earth is it buried within Data Stream?

Answer (score 3):

Click on setting on lower left -> Click on admin -> select "data streams" under property -> Expand the web tab -> scroll down and click on google site tag

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely solve your problem :)

> Since creating the video, Google has changed the default version of Google Analytics from Universal analytics to Google Analytics 4.  However, you can still create a universal analytics property.  To create an Universal analytics property, click on the "Show advanced options" link on the first page of the create property setup wizard, and then select the toggle to "Create a Universal analytics property". This will give you the tracking ID I mention in the video.

Credits goes to Guiding Digital youtube channel https://youtu.be/__PctBcNZ-c